# SSIS Can't Process DataCube

Tags: sql, ssis, ssas, data-cube

Trying to create an SSIS package to process a Datacube. Using SMS 2008, I've created a package to run where the cube lives and I keep getting an error,

SSIS package "SalesCubeProcess.dtsx" starting.
Error: 0x0 at Sales Cube Analysis Process in SSAS01, Analysis Services Processing Task: The connection either timed out or was lost.
Task failed: Sales Cube Analysis Process in SSAS01
SSIS package "SalesCubeProcess.dtsx" finished: Success.
The program '[2988] SalesCubeProcess.dtsx: DTS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Any ideas??? I'm at a loss here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to process the cube in BIDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a connectivity issue.  Here's how I'd attack it...

1. Test connection manager in BIDS
2. Test SSIS package in BIDS

If both of those pass...then please update your question with the specifics of how you are executing the SSIS package (SQL Server Agent Job, manually after logging into Integration Services, etc).  Thanks!